# Getting around using Absolute Positioning

Tags: css, z-index, padding, margin, css-position

Hey all, I have a image I am absolutely positioning and it works perfect on firefox, but in a totally different spot on safari, Is there any other way to position it where I want(on top of another image) without using absolute positioning. I have already tried margin and padding and that does not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're likely experiencing [invalid markup](http://validator.w3.org/), a missing [doctype](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/doctype/), or both.